# Open vim with nerdtree if its open from inside a particular directory

Tags: vimrc, plugin-nerdtree

I have the following lines in my vimrc:

```
autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree
autocmd VimEnter * wincmd p
```

As a result the nerdtree plugin always opens when I load vim. How can I change the behaviour to load nerdtree iff vim is invoked from a particular directory.

For example, when open `$ vim file.py` from inside `~/workspace/something/` the loaded `vim` must load with nerdtree as I want any instance of vim involked from inside `~/workspace` to have nerdtree loaded by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editing the line to check for directory fixed my problem.

```
autocmd VimEnter */workspace/* NERDTree| wincmd p
```